# Issues with creating a stream in Python

Tags: python, flask, aspose.words

I'm attempting to create a stream for the .docx file returned from the user upload. I tried using `.seek(0)`, `.read()`, and `.stream()` but each returned an error. Is there something I am missing? The .docx is sucessfully returned as a `<class 'werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage'>` object but I'm having trouble making it into a stream for the `aspose.words` module to read.

```py
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        document = request.files['document']
        stream = io.FileIO(document.read())
        doc = aw.Document(stream)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use either `io.BytesIO(document.read())` or `io.BufferedReader(document)` instead of `io.FileIO(document.read())`.

`io.FileIO` expects file name as an input parameter.

Comment: It worked! Been spinning my wheels on this for a few weeks now. Thank you for the help!